# MySQL queries very slow - occasionally

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, query-cache

I'm running MariaDB 10.2.31 on Ubuntu 18.4.4 LTS.
On a regular basis I encounter the following conundrum - especially when starting out in the morning, that is when my DEV environment has been idle for the night - but also during the day from time to time.

I have a table (this applies to other tables as well) with approx. 15.000 rows and (amongst others) an index on a VARCHAR column containing on average 5 to 10 characters.
Notably, most columns including this one are `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_EXTRACT(....)) STORED` since 99% of my data comes from a REST API as JSON-encoded strings (and conveniently I simply store those in one column and extract everything else).

When running a query on that column `WHERE colname LIKE 'text%'` I find query-result durations of i.e. 0.006 seconds. Nice. When I have my query `EXPLAIN`ed, I can see that the index is being used.
However, as I have mentioned, when I start out in the morning, this takes way longer (14 seconds this morning). I know about the query cache and I tried this with query cache turned off (both via `SET GLOBAL query_cache_type=OFF` and `RESET QUERY CACHE`). In this case I get consistent times of approx. 0.3 seconds - as expected.

So, what would you recommend I should look into? Is my DB sleeping? Is there such a thing?

Comment: This probably is a question for https://dba.stackexchange.com, but to start somewhere: is your database server doing something overnight/is someone accessing it (e.g. backups, the rest api, ...)? This includes all databases on that server.

Comment: I do have a daemon running which continuously fetches and inserts the mentioned JSON-data (and does other cleanup work). Meaning that the database should be in use at all times even when noone is using the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that could be going on:

1) Cold caches (overnight backup, mysqld restart, or large processing job results in this particular index and table data being evicted from memory).

2) Statistics on the table go stale and the query planner gets confused until you run some queries against the table and the statistics get refreshed. You can force an update using ANALYZE TABLE table_name.

3) Query planner heisenbug. Very common in MySQL 5.7 and later, never seen it before on MariaDB so this is rather unlikely.

You can get to the bottom of this by enablign the following in the config:

```
log_output='FILE'
log_slow_queries=1
log_slow_verbosity='query_plan,explain'
long_query_time=1
```

Then review what is in the slow log just after you see a slow occurrence. If the logged explain plan looks the same for both slow and fast cases, you have a cold caches issue. If they are different, you have a table stats issue and you need to cron `ANALYZE TABLE` at the end of the over night task that reads/writes a lot to that table. If that doesn't help, as a last resort, hard code an index hint into your query with `FORCE INDEX (index_name)`.

Comment: heisenbug still happen, I have seen it in the early 10.0 days. Wrote [innodb_stats_traditional=OFF](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_stats_traditional) to improve stats gathering. Before reverting to index forceing look at persistent stats IMHO.

Comment: After I deactivated my daemon I seem to get better results, so I believe its many read/write operations are the culprit. This is just after a short time however.
Also, my daemon seems to build up large RAM usage (which is one of the things on my TODO list). Could this push out pages from the buffer pool or is this of fixed size?

Comment: The buffer pool is reserved, memory pressure won't push it out (but things may crash due to OOM condition). I suggest you allocate your memory in huge pages (large-pages=1 in my.cnf and you will have to configure the huge page allocation separately using sysctl, it may require a reboot to free up enough contiguous memory). The upshot of huge pages is that the memory allocated to them is invisible to other processes, and they are unswappable, so the buffer pool cannot be pushed out to swap - another thing that may be happening to you if there is large memory pressure.

Answer (score 0):

Enable your [slow query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/#configuring-the-slow-query-log-verbosity) with `log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain` and the `long_query_time` sufficient to catch the results. See if occasionally its using a different (or no) index.

Before you start your next day, look at `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "innodb_buffer_pool%"` and after your query look at the values again. See how many buffer pool reads vs read requests are in this status output to see if all are coming off disk.

As @Solarflare mentioned, backups and nightly activity might be purging the innodb buffer pool of cached data and reverting bad to disk to make it slow again. As part of your nightly activites you could set [innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now) to save the pages being hot before scripted activity and [innodb_buffer_pool_load_now=1](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_load_now) to restore it.

Comment: Thank you, I will see what I can gather from the STATUS outputs. It seems I will have to go deep to find the cause. ;)

Comment: And learn some valuable things in the meantime. Happy learning. Look forward to seeing follow up questions on dba.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: most definetly! :D thank you. I will update my progress.

Answer (score 0):

Shout-out and Thank you to everyone giving valuable insight!
From all the tips you guys gave I think I am starting to understand the problem better and beginning to narrow it down:

First thing I found was my default `innodb_buffer_pool_size` of 134 MB. With the sort and amount of data I'm processing this is ridiculously low - so I was able to increase it.
Very helpful post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27341
And from the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html

Now that I have increased it to close to 2GB and am able to monitor its usage and RAM usage in general (cli: cat /proc/meminfo) I realize that my 4GB RAM is in fact on the low side of things. I am nowhere near seeing any unused overhead (buffer usage still at 99% and free RAM around 100MB).

I will start to optimize RAM usage of my daemon next and see where this leads - but this will not free enough RAM altogether.

@danblack mentioned `innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now` and `innodb_buffer_pool_load_now`. This is an interesting approach to maybe use whenever the daemon accesses the DB as I would love to separate my daemon's buffer usage from the front end's (apparently this is not possible!). I will look into this further but as my daemon is running all the time (not only at night) this might not be feasible.

@Gordan Bobic mentioned "refreshing" DBtables by using `ANALYZE TABLE tableName`. I found this to be quite fast and incorporated it into the daemon after each time it does an extensive read/write. This increases daemon run times by a few seconds but this is no issue at all. And I figure I can't go wrong with it :)

So, in the end I believe my issue to be a combination of things: Too small buffer size, too small RAM, too many read/write operations for that environment (evicting buffered indexes etc.).
Also I will have to learn more about memory allocation etc and optimize this better (large-pages=1 etc).